# How to set bgcolor of the future dates

Tags: pine-script

I am working on pine script application that set backgroud colors between dates in tradingview editor.

The following code sets backgroud color of bars:

```
start_date = timestamp(2023, 12, 6, 0, 0)
end_date = timestamp(2023, 12, 7, 0, 0)

bgcolor((time>=start_date and time<=end_date) ? color.new(color.yellow, 90) : na)
```

but I have future dates in my data, they does not appear on screen. So how can I set bgcolor of them?

(I used bgcolor in here but if there is another way you can offer for me.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with `bgcolor()` as you cannot specify a time with it.

As a workaround, you can use two `line`s and fill between them with `linefill` so it would have the same effect.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

start_time = timestamp(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
end_time = timestamp(2024, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0)

is_in_time = (time >= start_time) and (time <= end_time)
bg_col = color.new(color.blue, 85)

bgcolor(is_in_time ? bg_col : na)

var box_created = false

if (is_in_time and not box_created)
    l1 = line.new(start_time, close + syminfo.mintick, start_time, close - syminfo.mintick, color=bg_col, extend=extend.both, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    l2 = line.new(end_time, close + syminfo.mintick, end_time, close - syminfo.mintick, color=bg_col, extend=extend.both, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    linefill.new(l1, l2, bg_col)
    box_created := true
```

On Dec, 17 (today), the `bgcolor()` stops working but the workaround works.

[image]